# Granular permission for a single KeePass database

Tags: permissions, password-management, keepass, keepassx, keepassxc

Let's say we have a single KeePass database file `database.kdbx` in a shared folder among multiple persons.

In KeePass, how to make different user permissions for access to each password? Example:

```
                                    Me      Bob     Alice   Eve

Company .com registrar account      X   
Account on website ABC              X       X
Account on website DEF              X               X       X
Account on website GHI              X       X       X
Bob's webmail                               X
Alice's webmail                                     X
Eve's webmail                                               X
```

Do we need multiple "master passwords"?

Or is there a more general solution for this situation?

Notes:

- we would like to keep a standalone .exe solution, and no browser-based / cloud solution
- related [question](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/60f9fdea/) (but maybe obsolete, 2015)
- I would like to avoid having to deal with many different .kdbx databases like `admin.kdbx`, `admin+bob.kdbx`, `admin+alice+eve.kdbx`, `admin+bob+alice.kdbx`, etc., because this is not very flexible

Comment: Does this help? https://ijalba.wordpress.com/2021/09/14/setup-a-keepass-db-for-different-users-and-roles/

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks! It looks complicated though. (NB: I can deal with that, but my non-power-user cowokers won't like this :))

Comment: LOL :-D If you get it resolved with that, please do write a how-to for an answer :-)

Comment: What is not clear from the question is: If multiple users "share" a password database, is each of them allowed to change that password? Meaning: is the shared access read-only, or is it read-write? Basically I think having multiple databases is the way to go. Or better: Avoid sharing passwords!

Answer (score 2):

There are only two solutions to your question :

1. Use an enterprise password product (costly)
2. Use multiple separate password databases (rigorous requirements).

For the first solution, there exist multiple products, some of which are:

- [KeePass Pro](https://www.teams-pro.com/en/blog/keepass-pro-the-password-management-solution-for-microsoft-teams/) for Microsoft Teams
- [Delinea Enterprise Password Management](https://delinea.com/what-is/enterprise-password-management)
- [Pleasant Password Server](https://pleasantpasswords.com/)
- [Password State](https://www.clickstudios.com.au/)
- And so on.

There are no miracle solutions. If an enterprise password product is too
costly to go this way, you have to go in the direction of do-it-yourself.

Below is one
[description](https://www.reddit.com/r/KeePass/comments/vsn7fi/comment/ifdpt7k/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
of such a solution:

> Our strategy at the agency I worked for was one file for each team, and one file for each user:
>
> Each team has a DB file on a network location, secured through network
> permissions for that team's AD group, and only the team members know
> the passphrase of the DB. This provides two levels of security. Any
> passwords needed by the entire team go here. For us this was
> test/verification service accounts. (If at all possible we would avoid
> having these types of shared credentials, and issue credentials to
> each team member, but some things that were typically backend services
> didn't lend themselves to per use authentication, and we needed
> credentials for troubleshooting/testing shared by the team.)
>
> Each individual has their own DB file in their personal network share
> accessible only by them. Again the network share permissions. Of
> course the put credentials here for any accounts issued by them that
> don't need to be shared.
>
> Keypass makes this easy since you can have both your own and the team
> DB file open in two tabs. You can also put the team passphrase in your
> personal DB so that you only really need to memorize your personal DB
> passphrase.
>
> It's important that team members are stressed the importance of a
> strong passphrase, and never copy the DB locally. I might even
> consider requiring higher iterations per org policy.
>
> You can always create a DB on the fly for a one off password share. If
> you have OneDrive then it's easy for someone to create a DB, share it
> to a specific user in the enterprise, call them and give them the
> passphrase for the DB over the phone. Then once they confirm they've
> copied the entry into their personal DB then you delete the shared DB.
> Might seem nonsensical to tell them a DB passphrase when you could
> just give them the password you're trying to share, but often times
> with something like a system/service password it's very long and there
> will be a delay before the recipient can get it into their system in a
> way they can verifiy the credential which might result in followup
> calls/double checking. So it's alot easier to give them a relatively
> simpler but still strong passphrase for the DB over the phone, let
> them open the DB file while on the phone to verify they are able to
> get it, then they can copy the service/credential password without
> worrying about making an error.